# quiero usar un dato de un documento embebido para compararlo en un if, y si ya existe ese dato, no dejar crearlo

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

tengo una base de datos con la colección de hoteles y en este se encuentra un subdocumento llamado habitaciones con nombre, precio y disponibilidad, el punto es que quiero obtener el nombre para compararlo con el que el administrador ingrese para ver si ya existe y si ya existe no dejar agregar la habitación al hotel

```js
if (params.nombreHabitacion && params.precio) {
  Hotel.find({
    'habitaciones.nombreHabitacion': params.nombreHabitacion
  }, (err, habitacionEncontrada) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send({
      mensaje: 'Error en la peticion'
    });
    console.log(habitacionEncontrada)
    if (!habitacionEncontrada) return res.status(500).send({
      mensaje: 'Esta habitación no existe'
    });
    console.log(habitacionEncontrada)
    if ( /*"aqui necesito el nombre de la habitacion que está en el documento == params.nombreHabitacion*/ ) {
      return res.status(500).send({
        mensaje: 'Esta habitación ya existe'
      });
    } else {
      Hotel.findOneAndUpdate(hotelId, {
        $push: {
          habitaciones: {
            nombreHabitacion: params.nombreHabitacion,
            precio: params.precio,
            disponibilidad: disponibilidad
          }
        }
      }, {
        new: true
      }, (err, habitacionAgregada) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({
          mensaje: 'Error en la peticion'
        });
        if (!habitacionAgregada) return res.status(500).send({
          mensaje: 'No se ha agregado la habitacion'
        });

        return res.status(200).send({
          habitacionAgregada
        })
      });
    }
  })
} else {
  return res.status(500).send({
    mensaje: 'No puede dejar parametros vacíos'
  });
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme ya que no logro obtener el dato

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir un ejemplo de documento para saber exactamente la estructura del mismo y poder darte una respuesta adecuada? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esporque la funcion find es asincrona, sino usas await te devulve una promesa y no un resultado, debes guardar el resultado en una variable y luego usar if para verificar si se encontro la habitacion

```
let encontrado = await Hotel.find({
    'habitaciones.nombreHabitacion': params.nombreHabitacion

if(encontrado != null){
 //el nombre ya existe
}
```